# Modern tkinter menus in Windows

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

Is it possible, using `tkinter`, to create a modern menu with a divider on the left for icons?

[image: Example screenshot of the desired menu]

It was introduced in Windows Vista, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Have you tried `.add_separator()`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it would have been a crazy revelation, but no, it still shows the [old kind of menu](http://i.imgur.com/s3SxApF.jpg).

Comment: So which divider are you talking about? The one at the left-hand edge? Tkinter may not be the best GUI toolkit if you want to make native-looking apps.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, the *divider for icons* on the left. If it's not possible then that's the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter **can not** provide native looking windows. If you're looking to make a more modern program, I'd suggest using wxPython or PyQt.

You could probably just use the menu from either and attach it to a Tk window somehow, but it's not recommended.